# Recursive Function that returns all substrings of a string

Tags: c++, string, recursion, vector, substring

I need to implement a function in C++,

```
vector<string> generateSubstrings(string s),
```

that returns a vector of all substrings of a string. For example, the substrings of the string “rum” are the seven strings

“r”, “ru”, “rum”, “u”, “um”, “m”, “”.

The function has to be recursive and has to return the results as a vector.

Here is my code so far. It's only printing  "r", "ru" and  "rm". I'm having alot of trouble implementing this function. I've been working on this for the past few hours but I just can't figure out how to get it working as stated, so any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<string> generateSubstrings(string s, int num){ 
    int index = num;
    int SIZE = s.size();

    vector<string> substrings;


    if(index == s.size()){//BASE CASE
        string temp = s.substr(index,1);
        substrings.push_back(temp);
    }
    else{
        for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i){ 
            string temp = s.at(index) + s.substr(i,i);
            substrings.push_back(temp);
        }   
        generateSubstrings(s, num + 1);
    }     
    return substrings; 
} 

int main() { 
    vector<string> vec(20);
    vec = generateSubstrings("rum", 0);


    cout << endl << endl;cout << "PRINTING VECTOR" << endl;

    for ( int i = 0; i<vec.size();++i){
        cout << vec.at(i);
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "DONE";
}
```

Comment: What are the substrings of "rumm"? Does it have two "m" substrings or should it have only one of these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your assignment there is written that the recursive function has to be declared like

```
vector<string> generateSubstrings(string s),
```

But you are trying to make another function recursive that declared like

```
vector<string> generateSubstrings(string s, int num);
```

So in any case your solution does not satisfy the requirement of the assignment.

The function can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> generateSubstrings( std::string s )
{
    if ( s.empty() ) return {};

    std::vector<std::string> v;
    v.reserve( s.size() * ( s.size() + 1 ) / 2 );

    for ( std::string::size_type i = 0; i < s.size(); i++ )
    {
        v.push_back( s.substr( 0, i + 1 ) );
    }

    for ( const std::string &t : generateSubstrings( s.substr( 1 ) ) )
    {
        v.push_back( t );
    }

    return v;
}

int main() 
{
    std::string s( "rum" );

    for ( const std::string &t : generateSubstrings( s ) )
    {
        std::cout << t << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
r
ru
rum
u
um
m
```

If you need also to include an empty string then you should change condition

```
    if ( s.empty() ) return {};
```

in appropriate way. For example

```
   if ( s.empty() ) return { "" };
```

Also in this case you should write

```
   v.reserve( s.size() * ( s.size() + 1 ) / 2 + 1 );
```

Also you can replace the loop in the shown function with method insert. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> generateSubstrings( std::string s )
{
    if ( s.empty() ) return {};

    std::vector<std::string> v;
    v.reserve( s.size() * ( s.size() + 1 ) / 2 );

    for ( std::string::size_type i = 0; i < s.size(); i++ )
    {
        v.push_back( s.substr( 0, i + 1 ) );
    }

    std::vector<std::string> v2 = generateSubstrings( s.substr( 1 ) );

    v.insert( v.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end() );

    return v;
}

int main() 
{
    std::string s( "rum" );

    for ( const std::string &t : generateSubstrings( s ) )
    {
        std::cout << t << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output will be the same as shown above.

Here is a program modification that includes an empty string in the vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> generateSubstrings( std::string s )
{
    if ( s.empty() ) return { "" };

    std::vector<std::string> v;
    v.reserve( s.size() * ( s.size() + 1 ) / 2 + 1 );

    for ( std::string::size_type i = 0; i < s.size(); i++ )
    {
        v.push_back( s.substr( 0, i + 1 ) );
    }

    std::vector<std::string> v2 = generateSubstrings( s.substr( 1 ) );

    v.insert( v.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end() );

    return v;
}

int main() 
{
    std::string s( "rum" );

    for ( const std::string &t : generateSubstrings( s ) )
    {
        std::cout << t << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i have a question, when you do `for ( const std::string &t : generateSubstrings( s ) )`, is `generateSubstrings( s )` evaluated each time ?

Comment: @Guiroux  It evaluates only once.

Comment: I keep getting an error saying, "reference variable "t" requires an initializer." I'm not sure how to fix this, as I'm not familiar with the syntax you're using for those for loops.

Comment: this syntax is C++11 standards, you must use -std=c++11 option for g++ for example

Comment: @Domino  Use the second modification of the function. It does not use the range based for loop. As for the loop in main then you may write main as you like without the loop.:)

Comment: I got it working and I'm looking through it  to make sure I understand it all. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer using Python. It prints the correct result for "rum", but for "rumm" it prints two "m" substrings for obvious reasons:

```
def substrings(s):
  result = []
  if len(s) == 0:
    result.append("")
  if len(s) > 0:
    result += substrings(s[1:])
  for n in range(1,len(s)+1):
    result.append(s[0:n])
  return result

print substrings("rum")

print substrings("rumm")
```

The idea of the algorithm is the following: for "rum", the substrings are the substrings of "um" followed by "r", "ru" and "rum". For "um", the substrings are the substrings of "m" followed by "u" and "um". For "m", the substrings are the substrings of "" followed by "m". For "", the substrings are simply "". So, the final list is "", "m", "u", "um", "r", "ru", "rum".

Although this isn't C++, you should be able to translate the code to C++. But that may not necessarily be what you want as "rumm" has two "m" substrings. If you think that "rumm" should have only one "m" substring, please leave a comment and I'll post another answer.

Comment: The question is clearly tagged C++, so instead of posting a python code, you should have instead posted the right algorithm. There's no guarantee that the OP knows python.

Comment: You're right. I now explain the idea of the algorithm in my answer for the use case of the string "rum". However, I have to point out that Python is practically executable pseudocode and by answering in Python I have the benefit that the answer is easily understandable in addition to the benefit that I can verify the algorithm works.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should pay attention about code indent.
Then, I don't look your code, I wrote some code to achieve your aim, as follow:

```
void generateSubstrings(string s, int num, vector<string> &sta)
{
    if (num == s.size())
        return;

    auto b = begin(s) + num;

    string temp = "";
    temp += *b;
    sta.push_back(temp);
    b++;
    while (b != end(s))
    {

        temp += *b;
        sta.push_back(temp);
        b++;

    }
    generateSubstrings(s, num + 1, sta);
}
```

Comment: What is different in this code than in the question? Please add an explanation, so other users can benefit from this answer. This answer has been marked for deletion as "Very Low Quality", So, Please improve it.